# How to fix "UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView"

Tags: android

I want to saveInstance when changing from portrait to landscape. But when I try to restoreInstance of my letter button's background and enable, it tells me this error.
The program went well when I comment out those codes.

This is letter class

```
public class Letter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] letters;
    private LayoutInflater letterInf;

    public Letter(Context c){
        letters = new String[26];
        for(int a = 0; a < letters.length; a++){
            letters[a] = ""+(char)(a+'A');
        }
        letterInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return letters.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button btnLetter;
        if(convertView == null){
            btnLetter = (Button) letterInf.inflate(R.layout.letter, null, false);
        }else{
            btnLetter = (Button) convertView;
        }
        btnLetter.setText(letters[position]);
        return btnLetter;
    }
}
```

This is what I try to restore onRestoreInstance (the whole version)

```
 @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    currPart = savedInstanceState.getInt("currPart");
    numChars = savedInstanceState.getInt("numChars");
    numCorr = savedInstanceState.getInt("numCorr");
    int[] savedBodyPartVisibility = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("bodyPartVisibility");
    for(int i = 0; i<savedBodyPartVisibility.length; i++){
        bodyParts[i].setVisibility(savedBodyPartVisibility[i]);
    }
    //saved word
    currWord = savedInstanceState.getString("currWord");
    hint = savedInstanceState.getString("hint");
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){//get orientation
        tvHint.setText("Hint:"+hint);// if landscape, show hint
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This is landscape!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    charViews = new TextView[currWord.length()];

    wordLayout.removeAllViews();

    for(int c = 0; c<currWord.length(); c++){
        charViews[c] = new TextView(this);
        charViews[c].setText(""+currWord.charAt(c));

        charViews[c].setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        charViews[c].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        charViews[c].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        charViews[c].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letter_bg);
        wordLayout.addView(charViews[c]);

    }
    //saved charView
    int[] savedCharViewColor = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("charViewColor");
    for(int i = 0; i< savedCharViewColor.length; i++){
        charViews[i].setTextColor(savedCharViewColor[i]);
    }
    //int numLetters = savedInstanceState.getInt("numLetters");
    //letter enable//letter button background color
    boolean[] savedLetterEnable = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("letterEnable");
    int[] savedLettersColor = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("lettersColor");
    for(int i = 0; i<savedLetterEnable.length; i++){
        letters.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(savedLetterEnable[i]);
        //letters.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(savedLettersColor[i]);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please post the whole onRestoreInstanceState method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restore it this way because views are recycled in RecyclerView/ListView. It means that only some of them is rendered and when you scroll it reuses already rendered views.

So in most of the cases it will not have that many child views as items in datasource.

The proper approach is to store information about items' state inside adapter.

I have created simple example to give you an idea how could it look. Note that `setOnSelectedListener(new OnSelectedListener(){...}` is fake code and you should write proper listener (onClick, or if you want to use Checkboxes then onCheckedCHange or anything else based on your needs).

```
 public class Letter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] letters;
    private LayoutInflater letterInf;
    private Set<String> selectedLetters = new ArraySet();

    public Letter(Context c){
        letters = new String[26];
        for(int a = 0; a < letters.length; a++){
            letters[a] = ""+(char)(a+'A');
        }
        letterInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    Set<String> getState() {
        return selectedLetters;
    }

    void restoreState(Set<String> selectedLetters) {
        this.selectedLetters = selectedLetters;
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return letters.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button btnLetter;
        if(convertView == null){
            btnLetter = (Button) letterInf.inflate(R.layout.letter, null, false);
        }else{
            btnLetter = (Button) convertView;
        }
        if(selectedLetters.contains(letters[position])) {
            btnLetter.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            btnLetter.setSelected(false);
        }
        btnLetter.setOnSelectedListener(new OnSelectedListener() {
           void onSelected(..., boolean isSelected) {
               if(isSelected) {
                   selectedLetters.add(letters[position]);
               } else {
                   selectedLetters.remove(letters[position]);
               }
           } 
        });
        btnLetter.setText(letters[position]);
        return btnLetter;
    }
}
```

Then whenever you save state, you get it from adapter `getState` and put it in savedInstanceState.

Whenever you restore state you get it from savedState and put in adapter `restoreState`

Comment: You mean I need to write a setOnClickListener of my btnLetter?
But what is boolean isSelected means in your suggested code?
what should I write in on onClick()? Thank you.

Comment: I changed my Letter class
`
//new add
        btnLetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedLetters.add(letters[position]);
            }
        });
        if(selectedLetters.contains(letters[position])){
            btnLetter.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            btnLetter.setEnabled(false);
        }
        //new add
`
but it enabled all my buttons first

Comment: is `selectedLetters` empty before you click anything?